# RSS link to open in WebView(iOS)

Tags: ios, uitableview, rss, webview, nsstring

My app has an RSS tableView and at another page a WebView. I can open WebView with the click of any item in the RSS but I can't pass the link and display the website in the WebView
below is my code

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

    NSString * storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"link"];


    // clean up the link - get rid of spaces, returns, and tabs...
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];


    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    browserScreen = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:browserScreen.view];


    // open in Safari --> this line works perfect but I want to open the link in my own Webview so I commented it out
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];

 }
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the UIWebView is in your DetailsViewController, you have to set the URL in the WebView that is in your DetailsViewController.

```
browserScreen.webView.request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
```

Comment: thanks but that didn't work, and my problem here is to use storyLink as a global string. webView does not sees storyLink in the DetailsViewController

Comment: I found another solution, what I need was to use a globel string to pass the "storyLink" to webView. Still, thanks a lot for taking your time